# SSAS: Average calculation on elements and time

Tags: sql-server, ssas, average, measure

First of all, the data:

In fact table, I have the following data:

```
Date            Value
2014-05-12  0,5251137
2014-05-12  0,5266633
2014-05-12  2,3249296
```

I want to calculate the average in the cube. So, I did

```
[Measures].[Value] / [Measures].[Count]
```

The result gives me 1.33333, but the real value is ~1.1255. I know, SSAS rounds values, so the calculation for the given values is: (1 + 1 + 2) / 3 = 1.33333..

What to do, to get the value of ~1.1255... ?

Second one... nice to have the average. But, maybe if I have 3 values for 2014-05-12 with average of 1.5 and 8 values for 2014-05-13 with average of 5.5, it calculates the average based on the sum value. So the result is 3.5, not 4.409. How to achieve the correct behaviour?

**Update**: As mentioned in my second comment, I found the solution. Thanks for reading...

Comment: why aren't you just using `average` for your measure?, and how was the `value` measure defined?, is it `SUM` or something else?

Comment: the [Measures].[Value] is a sum. What exactly do you mean by "using average"? Simply avg(value/count)?

Comment: it seems to me, that it was late yesterday! I did not recognize, that I have to re-add the measures after changing the underlying data type. Value has been bigint and I changed to double... but the measure was still set to bigint. shame on me... so everything is fine now and the calculation is correct.